# What modification is needed so a creature can't fart, while it can still excrete?

Tags: science-based, biology, xenobiology

As the title says, what modification is needed, so a creature cannot fart while still being able to excrete their waste?

So creatures that can't excrete or doesn't have an anus like the [Demodex](https://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/scaled/2014/06/14/article-2657848-1EC2E01A00000578-500_636x382.jpg) is out of this question.

Is this possible?

Comment: mind the language you use, please.

Comment: Big difference between can't and doesn't here. It's possible in theory not to produce gas during digestion for example. Just say it doesn't, the rest are technical details about microorganisms and somehow I think it's not that kind of world. However, if a solid or liquid can fit through something, a gas can as well.

Comment: "Fart" isn't bad language. The NHS use it on their website, for heaven's sake. https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/Flatulence/

Answer (score 1):

The modification to prevent an organism from eructating or breaking wind (thus, avoiding the f**t word) is simple. Its microbiome would have to be highly efficient and was capable of consuming metabolic products that would tend to be gases. Therefore, its alimentary system wouldn't be producing gases in sufficient qualities for them to be expelled from its fundament. It would still excrete matter, but this would be in the form of solids and liquids.

Comment: i was mean an organs or something that make the creature never generate eructating, but i guess this acceptable too, and  i guess scientifically or probably the only way to it.

Comment: Metabolism not producing any gas would require a whole new biochemistry. Consuming the methane would produce CO2 and H2O...

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica CO2 is conveniently soluble. With a bit of an increase in muscle tone, this species could be the first to produce effervescent excrement. Failing that, a microbiome including components that produce suitable carbonates might be possible, though it does seem likely to be more calorifically intensive that just letting the gas out.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica Not so new. "These bacteria are called methanotrophs, a name that literally means “fueled by methane.” Methanotrophs survive extreme conditions by eating methane. They house a unique protein called methane monooxygenase, or MMO" etc. Vide https://helix.northwestern.edu/blog/2017/09/bacteria-eat-methane  - I was aware work was done to reduce methane emission in ruminants, but methanotrophs were still a surprise.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Depending on the metabolic pathways they could go all the way to carbohydrates from a methane feedstock. Perhaps. But carbonates are also a possibility.

Comment: @LiJun Never underestimate bacteria. They have the most diversity of any organisms on the planet. Plus several billion years of evolution to make them adaptable to effectively every ecological niche in the biosphere.

Comment: @a4android methanotrophs release CO2, as would the metabolism of any methane-derived carbohydrates, taking you back to square one. You'd need a bacteria that was basically doing useless makework with a useful food source, whilst consumeing some _other_ food source to provide them with sufficient energy. You might be able to engineer such, but it is hard to see how such a pointless thing would arise naturally.

Comment: @StarfishPrime To achieve the OP's f**t-free organism a microbiome that totally suppresses gas production seems to be a plausible mechanism. We are talking about hypotheticals here. It is a folly to tell nature what it can or cannot do. Nature has a habit of slapping down mere human presumption.

Comment: @a4android no, nature that does pointless things pointlessly gets _devoured_ by nature that just settles down to the hard work of eating stupid evolutionary failures. Bacteria gotta eat. Bacteria that waste 50% of their intake on non-reproductive tomfoolery will be outcompeted by those that don't, which means that the total proportion of food they get will be _vastly_ reduced and their host will remain precisely as farty as they always were. Thems the breaks.

Comment: @StarfishPrime I am aware how messy biology & evolution can be, but this is about hypothetical biological speculation to attain an otherwise improbable end. Pun unintended, but proved irresistible. Lighten up, fella, this is all about possibility not probability, plausibility not reality. That said, I do understand your position, but this isn't about realistic biology.

Comment: @a4android my point is more or less that there is more than one choice here, where one set of choices is somewhat implausible, and the other is less so (carbonate-forming [bacterial biomineralisation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4771655/) is a thing, after all) and given the science-based nature of the question balance should probably tip _away_ from the unlikelier options.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this creature may have some kind of gas absorbing gland or organ that prevents it before excretion or something - possibly even has another organ to release it in a different way - probably soundlessly (so maybe something that looks a little like a vent/gills?)